# Is there any consensus on the capitalization of theories?

Tags: capitalization

Should the name of theories be capitalized? Does this depend on convention, the particular theory itself, or whether or not it contains a proper name?

I appreciate any input, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In both my science and English language training (at an English grammar school), I was taught that theory names do not have to be capitalized.  Some title Einstein's *theories* about relativity as the **Special Theory** of Relativity and the **General Theory of Relativity**, but you will find them named as just the **special theory of relativity** and **general theory of relativity** in scientific writing.

Incidentally, this is true in other languages as well, except German, which capitalizes all nouns regardless of historical importance.

Comment: French hardly capitalizes anything. And it seems this [includes](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativit%C3%A9_g%C3%A9n%C3%A9rale) les théories, [as well as](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lois_du_mouvement_de_Newton) les lois de la nature.

Answer (score 0):

If the theory really has a name (it is unique and therefore definite), then it should be capitalized: the Theory of Evolution (Darwin's).  If it definite merely by being possessed, then it need not be capitalized: Einstein's theory of gravity.